# Connecting codename one to php/mysql

Tags: php, xml-parsing, java-me, codenameone

I encountered the following error while building a mobile application with codename one.

The code is working in none codename project

```
public Actualite[] select(){
       try {
            ActualiteHandler matchHandler = new ActualiteHandler();
            // get a parser object
            SAXParser SAXparser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            // get an InputStream from somewhere (could be HttpConnection, for example)
            HttpConnection hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://localhost/abbes/select.php");//people.xml est un exemple
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(hc.openDataInputStream());
                        dis.toString();
            SAXparser.parse(dis, matchHandler);
            // display the result
            matches = matchHandler.getMatch();
             return matches;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

             return null;
   }
```

Here is the error

```
 error: cannot access File
 SAXparser.parse(dis, matchHandler);   
class file for java.io.File not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `SAXParser` nor `java.io.File` are supported by Codename One.

I also see you used `Connector` which is a J2ME class and unsupported.

You need to use [XMLParser](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/xml/XMLParser.html) and `FileSystemStorage`.

See the developer guide [covering this functionality](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html) here.

Comment: Just to add to this there is this new post covering connectivity to mysql in the backend: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/connecting-to-a-mysql-database.html